# I cannot understand the query

Tags: vbscript

I cannot understand this query?

```
select 
    @:vfOutBalance+@:vfHSSubTotal+@3+orpartpayment,@:vfOutBalance+@:vfHSSubTotal 
from 
    or_equip_upgrd_id
```

what does `@3` mean?

Comment: What is the context for this query? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a parameterized query.  The @ donotes the parameters that will be filled when the query is processed.